# Prove function is surjective?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I am trying to show the function $f: X \rightarrow S^2$ defined by 
\begin{equation}
f(x,y) = \Big(\sin\Big(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2}y\Big)\cdot \cos(x), \sin\Big(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2}y\Big)\cdot\sin(x), \cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2}y\Big)\Big)
\end{equation}
is surjective. I feel this should be simple but am struggling to come up with a point which produces $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: In order to check subjectivity you need to specify what is $X$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $X=\mathbb R^2$, since this will make things simple. For many other choices of $X$, the proof will be similar.

This map $f$ is the composition 
$$
\mathbb R^2\overset{\phi}{\to}\mathbb R^2\overset{\psi}{\to} \mathbb S^2,
$$
where $\phi(x,y)=(x,(\pi/2)(1-y))$, and $\psi(x,y)=(\sin y \cos x,\sin y \sin x,\cos y)$. $\phi$ is surjective, as it is essentially a linear function. $\psi(x,y)$ is also surjective, because for all $(X,Y,Z)$ such that $X^2+Y^2+Z^2=1$, we want to solve
$$
\tan x=Y/X,  \cos y= Z
$$
We can let 
$$
y=\pm \cos ^{-1} Z, x=\tan^{-1} (Y/X)+k\pi.
$$
Choose the sign of $y$ and $k$ to match the signs of $X,Y,Z$.

So $\psi$ is surjective. Then $f=\psi(\phi(\cdot))$ is surjective.